# Refreshing Jquery dialog content + JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, html, dialog, refresh

I need to display a table of records where on each row, there is an anchor tag clicking on which will open a Jquery dialog box. When I click on the link of each row, the dialog bog opens successfully (Currently, I have two rows and have hardcoded the ids of the anchor and div tags which I need to make them dynamic). Anyways, once the dialog opens, I have the option to uncheck and check certain check boxes and I make some updates. The updates should be getting reflected on the parent window which happens fine. However, when I open the dialog again, it opens with the initial data before making the updates instead of showing the dialog refreshed with the updates made.Also, it started throwing error messages saying "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

```
  $("#vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0").dialog(opt).dialog("open");});

 $("#vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0").dialog(
               {
                autoOpen : false,
                modal : false,
                resizable : false,
                height : 500,
                width : 750,
                buttons : [{
                text: "Submit", 
                click : function() {
                    var selNodes = "";
                  $('#artNodeAvailListId-0 input:checkbox:checked').each(
                     function() {
                        selNodes += $(this).val() + ",";
                      });


                  $("#frmAssignArticleHierarchy\\:hdnArticleNodeIds").attr("value",
                  selNodes);
                     frmAssignArticleHierarchy["frmAssignArticleHierarchy:btnRefreshArticleFilter"]
                 .click();

                  $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }]
         });
       };
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try dialog("destroy");
Check out the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I did try calling $(this).dialog("destroy"); before closing the dialog. It does not appear to work. Also, added    close:function(ev, ui) {
 alert('inside close');
 $(this).dialog("destroy"); 
}                                                                   when I open the second time after updating the dialog, the dialog itself does not open and shows the error message                  "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

Comment: I remeber creating a div on the fly with jquery. Upon close I used destroy and remove.
`
$("#dialogwrapper").dialog("destroy");
$("#dialogwrapper").remove();
`
I can't see the situation you in, but give that a try.

Comment: no Daniel..it does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you close the dialog, actually it doesn't remove the data in the dialog, so when it show again, it will show the existed data, so you need to add a close option which remove the `#vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0` content, just check the api of jquery dialog and you can find the code to do so.

```
$("#vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0").dialog(
               {
                autoOpen : false,
                modal : false,
                resizable : false,
                height : 500,
                width : 750,
close: function(){//add code to remove the data in vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0}
                buttons : [{
                text: "Submit", 

                click : function() {
                    var selNodes = "";
                  $('#artNodeAvailListId-0 input:checkbox:checked').each(
                     function() {
                        selNodes += $(this).val() + ",";
                      });


                  $("#frmAssignArticleHierarchy\\:hdnArticleNodeIds").attr("value",
                  selNodes);
                     frmAssignArticleHierarchy["frmAssignArticleHierarchy:btnRefreshArticleFilter"]
                 .click();

                  $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }]
         });
       };
```

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. However, it does not work..                                                               close:function(ev, ui) { alert('inside close'); $(this).dialog("destroy"); }

Comment: not that. You should remove the content in vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0, not just destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

Is  $("#vendoradmin-artnodesearch-popup-0") an element that you create on the fly?
Did you encapsulate your dialog id's. Can you use .ui-dialog as preceding selector? Are those id's unique?

```
  click: function () {
     var selNodes = "";
     $('.ui-dialog #artNodeAvailListId-0 input:checkbox:checked').each(

     function () {
         selNodes += $(this).val() + ",";
     });


     $("#frmAssignArticleHierarchy\\:hdnArticleNodeIds").attr("value",
     selNodes);


     $(this).dialog("close");
```

Somehow I think you may have conflicting id's.

Comment: I used the following to get this working                                          $('#vendorDtl').on('click', 'a.className', function(){

       var opt = { autoOpen : false, modal : false, resizable : false,
  height : 500, width : 750, buttons : {  "Submit" :   function() {
  //.....app specific code   
          $(this).dialog("close");
     }}};
$("#popup-"+rowNumber).dialog(opt).dialog("open");});                 I was able to resolve "Error in calling method open before dialog initialisation" and also by identifying the anchor tag that was dynamically generated & clicked.